# Trying to use Lua module fails on the command line

Tags: lua

I'm trying to learn how to use Lua modules.  I've been reading the following manual:

http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial

Unfortunately, I can't even get the first example working! I've done the following:

Created a "mymodule.lua" file which looks like this:

```
local mymodule = {}

function mymodule.foo()
    print("Hello World!")
end

return mymodule
```

Then from the command line, within the folder where the mymodule.lua file resides, I tried to do the following:

```
mymodule = require "mymodule"
```

But I get the following error message:

```
myserver:/usr/share/x/research/# mymodule = require "mymodule"
-ash: mymodule: not found
```

This works:

```
myserver:/usr/share/x/research/# local mymodule = require "mymodule"
```

But then when I try to run the foo() method it fails like so:

```
myserver:/usr/share/x/research/# mymodule.foo()
-ash: syntax error: bad function name
myserver:/usr/share/x/research/#
```

And I guess this makes sense because I declared mymodule as local instead of global on the command line.

I guess my question is why can't I declare the module globally on the command line.
The manual says that I should be running this from an "interactive interpreter".  I am using a standard commandline / terminal window in linux... could this be the issue? I usually have to prefix all lua commands with "lua ".

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Run `lua` in your shell first, that's the interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lua is not your shell. You need to run that code from inside the lua interpeter not at your shell prompt.

```
myserver:/usr/share/x/research/# lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> mymodule = require "mymodule"
> mymodule.foo()
```

Comment: i was just updating my question with the same comments.  but i didn't know how to launch the interpreter...thanks!

Comment: If you have your "script" code (the code that uses the module) in a file you can also just use `lua file.lua` to run it directly.